# browser not defined for ts-jest and puppeteer

Tags: typescript, jestjs, puppeteer

I am trying to create **snapshot-tests** with **puppeteer** for my [typescript create react app](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript). Regular testing with **jest is working fine**, but as soon as I am trying to create the snapshots with the **browser** and have to use the `browser` variable within my `.test.ts` file I'm being told that `browser is not defined`.

I can't seem to work around this problem even though I have been trying to resolve this issue for hours.

For reference, here are my jest settings within my `package.json` file:

```
  "jest": {
"preset": "jest-puppeteer-preset",
"collectCoverageFrom": [
  "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
],
"setupFiles": [
  "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
],
"testMatch": [
  "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.(j|t)s?(x)",
  "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).(j|t)s?(x)"
],
"testEnvironment": "node",
"testURL": "http://localhost",
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
  "^.+\\.tsx?$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/typescriptTransform.js",
  "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
  "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
},
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)$"
],
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
},
"moduleFileExtensions": [
  "web.ts",
  "ts",
  "web.tsx",
  "tsx",
  "web.js",
  "js",
  "web.jsx",
  "jsx",
  "json",
  "node",
  "mjs"
],
"globals": {
  "ts-jest": {
    "tsConfigFile": "tsconfig.test.json"
  }
}
```

And here are the dependencies I'm using:

```
"typescript": "^2.9.2",
"puppeteer": "^1.1.1",
"jest-image-snapshot": "^2.3.0",
"jest": "22.4.2",
"jest-puppeteer-preset": "^2.0.1",
"ts-jest": "22.0.1",
```

Any help would be appreciated a lot!

---

SOLUTION:
In combination with the marked answer below and [this guide](https://medium.com/ovrsea/headless-browser-testing-with-jest-and-puppeteer-2cf7d04f4af5) things worked out for me. For some reason I was trying to access `browser` as a global variable. Turns out I was doing things wrong from the very beginning. You are supposed to define browser like this:

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true // whether you want to run the test headless
  });
```

which ended up working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> browser not defined for ts-jest and puppeteer

Per the [jest puppeteer docs](https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer) you need to ensure you have `@types/jest-environment-puppeteer` installed as that provides the global `browser` definition.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This actually resolved that "browser" was marked as undefined within my editor. However while running the tests I'm still getting the same error of browser being undefined.

Comment: ok I got it working and edited my question to include the solution :)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the docs. I totally missed that and wasted way too much time on this. Looks like you need `@types/puppeteer`, `@types/jest-environment-puppeteer` and `@types/expect-puppeteer`